# If statement inside another one is false, return to the else of original if statement

Tags: php

Is there any way in PHP to return at else of first statement, if the second statement which is inside of first, is false

```
if($first == true) {
    //other code which is not necessary to mention here!
    if($second == true){
       // do smth
    }
    else{
       return to the else of $first statement
    }
    //other code which is not necessary to mention here!
}
else{
   //do smth else 
}
```

Comment: why can't you just regroup conditions to match cases?

Comment: put more descriptive title to avoid downvotings

Comment: @BoteaFlorin Please feel free to suggest a more descriptive title which does not ruin OP's intention because I find no issues with the current title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are multiple ways. For starters, just combine both the statements and give another condition:

```
if ($first == true && $second == true) {
    // do smth
} elseif ($first == true && $second == false) {
    // else of$first statement
} else {
    //do smth else 
}
```

This can be used as a guidance to get an idea to start. But if you can get a real world example, there can be conditions grouped, tailored to your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

While there is no native way to jump to outer `else`s from an inner `else`, but you can set a flag for later processing:

```
$do_else = false;

if($first == true) {
    //other code which is not necessary to mention here!
    if($second == true){
       // do smth
    }
    else{
       $do_else = true;
    }
    //other code which is not necessary to mention here!
}
else{
   $do_else = true;
   //do smth else
}

if($do_else){
   //do smth else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the answers above doesn t help you in the real situation, you can create a function for execute in 'else' statements to avoid code duplication